# Creating an onscroll ajax loader for iPhone (web app)

Tags: jquery, iphone, web-applications

I was wondering if it's possible to create an effect of auto loader while scrolling on iPhone, something like [this](http://www.webresourcesdepot.com/load-content-while-scrolling-with-jquery/)

If it's not possible, than how would you go about to program something similar to facebook's page refresher (when you scroll up/down) and it retrieves info.

Any help would be greatly appreciated on the matter,
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

See if this example helps [LazyTableImages](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/LazyTableImages/Introduction/Intro.html).

Or you can try to implement it in following way-

```
- (void)scrollViewWillBeginDragging:(UIScrollView *)scrollView {
    //Find what needs to be downloaded and download it.
}
```

Comment: I'm looking for a way to do that not in objective C, but rather for a web-app, running not natively.